# working with WMI and watching results with xml

Tags: xml, vbscript, wmi

I am new in vbscript and WMI. 
I wrote script which gives runtime error, that I cant solve.
If you have a time help me.

This is my code

```
Dim objWMIService 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

set oXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
set oRoot = oXMLDoc.CreateElement("WIN32")

oXMLDoc.appendChild oRoot

set oRootChild = oXMLDoc.createElement("LOGICALDISK")
oRoot.appendChild oRootChild

Set LogicalDisk = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk  ")

for each objLogicalDisk in LogicalDisk

set oCaption = oXMLDoc.createElement("Caption")
oCaption.text = objLogicalDisk.Caption
oRootChild.appendChild oCaption

set oDescription = oXMLDoc.createElement("Description")
oDescription.text = objLogicalDisk.Description
oCaption.appendChild oDescription

set oSize = oXMLDoc.createElement("Size")
oSize.text = objLogicalDisk.Size
oCaption.appendChild oSize

set oFreeSpace = oXMLDoc.createElement("FreeSpace")
oFreeSpace.text = objLogicalDisk.FreeSpace
oCaption.appendChild oFreeSpace

set oFileSystem = oXMLDoc.createElement("FileSystem")
oFileSystem.text = objLogicalDisk.FileSystem
oCaption.appendChild oFileSystem

next

oXMLDoc.save "test.xml"
```

And it gives this error

```
C:\Users\XXXX\Desctop\41.vbs(27, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch: 'oSize.text'
```

I thing that error occurs because of using uint64 type.(may be not)

Comment: This error is due to Devices with Removable Storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by Null values. Start with a function like

```
Function saveNull(vVal)
  If IsNull(vVal) Then
     saveNull = "<null>"
  Else
     saveNull = vVal
  End If
End Function
```

and use it like:

```
...
set oSize = oXMLDoc.createElement("Size")
oSize.text = saveNull(objLogicalDisk.Size)
oCaption.appendChild oSize
...
```

**WRT AMO1's contibution:**

Empty "removable storage" drives have neither size nor file system (facts which WMI reports by returning Null); checking the description to in/exclude specific drive types does not solve the problem, because inserting a media in such a drive makes those info available.

Comment: I have verified With Removable Storage & inserting media in it makes those info available.Thus your solution is more correct than mine & my solution will work only for Local storage

+1 For your Detail

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to "Devices with Removable Storage".I am sure as `size` not working ,`FreeSpace` & `FileSystem` will also not work.You can overcome it by adding `If <condtion> then`. Sample code

```
set oSize = oXMLDoc.createElement("Size")
If objLogicalDisk.Description="Local Fixed Disk" Then
oSize.text = objLogicalDisk.Size
oCaption.appendChild oSize
End If
```